# asp.net sorting Gridview custom datasource type

Tags: gridview, sorting, datasource

It seems that the only way to sort my gridview is by binding it to a datasource or datatable. I binded mine with a user custom list type and in this situation i can not convert my gridview datasource to a datatable or dataview. Is there any fast way, how to do this?

Regards

Comment: Is that similar to this scenario?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280948/datagridview-column-sorting-with-business-objects