# Int32? with IComparable

Tags: c#, .net

I have a DataGridView whose datasource is a BindingList. MyObj has a few nullable properties (like int? and DateTime?) I want to implement sorting to my binding list, so the DataGridView can sort the column when the user clicks on the column header.

After some digging around, I found and followed the answer of this question ([DataGridView Column sorting with Business Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280948/datagridview-column-sorting-with-business-objects)).

I can't get that solution to work for Nullable types because they don't implement IComparable. Even for classes that implement IComparable like String, ApplySortCore(...) fails when the String has a null value.

Is there a solution for this? Or do I have to implement a wrapper class for "Int32?" ?

eg

```
public class Int32Comparable : IComparable
{
    public int? Value { get; set; }

    #region IComparable<int?> Members

    public int CompareTo(object other)
    {
        // TODO: Implement logic here
        return -1;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Nullable<int>` may not implement `IComparable`, but surely `int` does. And `Nullable<T>` always boxes to `T` (for instance when you cast to an interface, such as `IComparable`, which is a boxing conversion). So comparing/sorting on nullable properties should not be a problem.

```
int? value = 1;
IComparable comparable = value; // works; even implicitly
```

So, the check in the sample at the top does not work right. Try this:

```
Type interfaceType = prop.PropertyType.GetInterface("IComparable");
// Interface not found on the property's type. Maybe the property was nullable?
// For that to happen, it must be value type.
if (interfaceType == null && prop.PropertyType.IsValueType)
{
    Type underlyingType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType);
    // Nullable.GetUnderlyingType only returns a non-null value if the
    // supplied type was indeed a nullable type.
    if (underlyingType != null)
        interfaceType = underlyingType.GetInterface("IComparable");
}
if (interfaceType != null)
   // rest of sample
```

One more addition: if you want null values to work as well (both string and nullable types), you could try this re-implementation of `SortCore(...)`:

```
protected override void ApplySortCore(PropertyDescriptor prop, ListSortDirection direction)
{
    IEnumerable<MyClass> query = base.Items;
    if (direction == ListSortDirection.Ascending)
        query = query.OrderBy( i => prop.GetValue(i) );
    else
        query = query.OrderByDescending( i => prop.GetValue(i) );
    int newIndex = 0;
    foreach (MyClass item in query)
    {
        this.Items[newIndex] = item;
        newIndex++;
    }
    this.OnListChanged(new ListChangedEventArgs(ListChangedType.Reset, -1));
}
```

There's no need to look for `IComparable` directly, just let the sorting methods themselves sort it out.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I also need to set _sortPropertyValue = prop;
            _sortDirectionValue = direction;
_isSortedValue = true; 
in order for the code to work. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Re "comparing/sorting on nullable properties should not be a problem." - unless the property has value `null`, in which case you will get a runtime exception. (I assume - I haven't tried it.)

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve, `OrderBy` and `OrderByDescending` don't mind when the property returns `null`. The default Comparer it uses will sort `null` values on top. You will only have a problem is when the list itself contains a `null` entry.

Answer (score 4):

When comparing your nullable types can you do something like this...

```
Int32? val1 = 30;
Int32 val2 = 50;

Int32 result = (val1 as IComparable).CompareTo(val2);
```