# Simplest way to make SortableBindingList use a stable sort

Tags: c#, sorting, bindinglist

There is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280948/datagridview-column-sorting-with-business-objects) of how to modify [SortableBindingList](http://www.timvw.be/2007/02/22/presenting-the-sortablebindinglistt/) to use a stable sort. However, there is an [updated version of SortableBindingList](http://www.timvw.be/2008/08/02/presenting-the-sortablebindinglistt-take-two/). What is the best way to modify this new version to use a stable sort? I think I would want a flag on the SortableBindingList to let the user of the SortableBindingList decide if they want to use (slower) stable sort or (faster) default sort.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can solve this problem by writing a stable sort extension method for `List<T>`:

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static void StableSort<T>(this List<T> list, IComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        var pairs = list.Select((value, index) => Tuple.Create(value, index)).ToList();
        pairs.Sort((x, y) =>
            {
                int result = comparer.Compare(x.Item1, y.Item1);
                return result != 0 ? result : x.Item2 - y.Item2;
            });
        list.Clear();
        list.AddRange(pairs.Select(key => key.Item1));
    }
}
```

and then in the new version of `SortableBindingList` change this line:

```
itemsList.Sort(comparer);
```

to:

```
itemsList.StableSort(comparer);
```

This works by using the unstable sort supplemented with a secondary key on the item index within the list.  Since this version doesn't use the pathologically slow **insertion sort** to achieve a stable sort, it should be fast enough for general use.